# Struts 2 how to reference a value with dynamic name on the valuestack

Tags: struts2, ognl

Say there is a value in valuestack of struts 2; when we code the jsp, we don't know what the exact variable name of this value, but we only know that the variable name of this value is saved in another variable name, say "XXX".

The question is how can get the value by using "XXX", I try this, but it is not working.

```
<s:property value="${XXX}"/>
```

Comment: Is there no way to refactor your action to standardize the way the variable is saved in the first place? That would be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

The action marshals data for the view, as such it should do the processing to get the required data. From the sounds of it, it sounds like the action could gather the appropriate data into a map.

However there are strange cases and you might have one.  But before addressing that if you only have the name of the variable where can it be assumed the real variable is? Is it in the value stack (and if so what is stopping you from accessing it directly)? If it is not on the value stack you'll need to enable static method assess and create an appropriate static method, since you are only provided with the name of the variable and assuming it is a property of a java bean you'll then need to use reflection or apache beanutils.

In general it is better to get what you need in the action for your views.

Also to set a value in your jsp's you are aware of the struts2 set tag (this is probably not what you want but there was a small chance it was so I included it)? See: http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/set.html